# mod_rewrite acting like redirect to another domain? How do I make a rewrite?

Tags: mod-rewrite

I want to redirect www.mydomain.com/store to http://store.anotherdomain.com/me

When I use RewriteRule ^store$ http://store.anotherdomain.com/me it ends up redirecting, meaning the URL changes, rather than remaining www.mydomain.com/store

What do I need it to do to do the rewrite properly?

When I use RewriteRule ^next$ /mydomain/subfolder/subfolder/subfolder is seems to work fine.

Answer (score 2):

```
RewriteRule ^store$ http://store.anotherdomain.com/me [P]
```

Note the **[P]** at the end. You'll also need to have the `mod_proxy` module enabled.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need mod_rewrite at all.

You need to enable mod_proxy and configure a [reverse proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypassreverse). You can even pass cookies from the other domain and make them look as if they were from your site.

```
ProxyPass /store/ http://store.anotherdomain.com/me/
ProxyPassReverse /store/ http://store.anotherdomain.com/me/
ProxyPassReverseCookieDomain store.anotherdomain.com www.mydomain.com
ProxyPassReverseCookiePath /me/ /store/
```